# В чём разница между TimeOut и KeepAliveTimeout?

Tags: веб-программирование, apache2, веб-сервер

Конфигурационный файл `/etc/apache2/apache.conf`.
Непонимание возникло из-за описания:

> KeepAliveTimeout Directive -  The number of seconds Apache will wait
>   for a subsequent request before closing the connection. Once a request
>   has been received, the **timeout value specified by the Timeout
>   directive applies**.

Что значит "Как только был получен запрос, применяется время ожидания, определенное в директиве TimeOut"? Как соприкасаются два этих таймаута?

Answer (score 2):

KeepAlive позволяет делать несколько запросов в одном TCP-подключении. Это особенно полезно для html-страниц с большим количеством изображений. Если KeepAlive установлен в Off, то для самой страницы и для каждого изображения будет создано отдельное подключение (которое нужно будет обработать master-процессу), что плохо и для сервера и для клиента. Так что для подобных случаев рекомендуется устанавливать KeepAlive в On. Для других применений (например для download-сервера) KeepAlive может быть бесполезен и даже вреден, т.к. при включенном KeepAlive сервер закрывает соединение не сразу, а ждет KeepAliveTimeout секунд нового запроса. Для того чтобы процессы не висели слишком долго в бесполезном ожидании, устанавливайте KeepAliveTimeout достаточно малым, около 5-10 секунд обычно достаточно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но вы лишь объяснили, зачем нужен KeepAlive, а мой вопрос состоит в разнице KeepAliveTimeout и TimeOut просто. Непонятка возникает из-за странного описания: "Once a request has been received, the timeout value specified by the Timeout directive applies". Я перевёл как "Как только был получен запрос, применяется время ожидания, определенное в директиве TimeOut" Что это значит? Описания директив нашёл тут - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#timeout.

Comment: А вам не ясна разница между KeepAliveTimeout и TimeOut после прочтения моего ответа?

Answer (score 2):

TimeOut - сколько секунд может выполняться обработка запроса сервером.
KeepAliveTimeout - сколько секунд держать соединение активным после ответа клиенту.